# ObjectDataSource - schema seems cached - unable to refresh

Tags: development, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

Within a Visual Studio 2012 Visual Web Part, I've created a simple FormView referencing an ObjectDataSource  to autogenerate an editable form.  Creating this the first time, there was no issue. However, after updating the data object from which the ObjectDataSource populates itself, and clicking "refresh schema" the source and form retain the same fields as when first created. I am unable to have it recognize either added or removed properties from the data object. The object has been annotated with `DataObject` and `DataObjectField`s.

Some information:

- The data object and the Visual Web Part are separate projects within the same solution

I've tried:

- deleting and recreating form and source controls from scratch
- changing the ID's of the form, source
- cleaning and rebuilding both projects
- removing and re-adding data object references
- closing and restarting VS
- switching between Source and Design views

Perhaps I'm missing something simple, any other questions I've read, this seems to have been the cause, but none have helped me so far.  Is there a cache which I could possibly manually delete to have the schema fetched or regenerated from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the data object's assembly being manually placed in and read from the IIS application's \bin. This is not automatically refreshed.

To prevent from having to manually update this each time the data object DLL is updated, the data object's DLL can be added to the Package's additional assemblies to be deployed to the GAC or \bin in the future.